# View filter on date "Less than or equal" AND NULL(empty)

Tags: views, datetime

I just made a view with some filters (date), I wonder how can I choose the operator to mix the options "Less than or equal" and NULL, in just one request? I can't do that with "Grouped filters", Should I hook the code? If that's so, where?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I could figured out this for myself, if anyone need it here is what you need to do:

1. Go to *sites/all/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_filter_numeric.inc*
2. In there:

   a. Inside the *function operators()->$operators = array(*

   b.

   ```
   'custom' => array(
   'title' => t('Title you want for your operator'),
       'method' => 'op_custom',
       'short' => t('<='),
       'values' => 1,
    )
   ```

c. Then around line 255 or so create a new function:

```
function op_custom($field) {
  $or = db_or()
  ->condition($field, $this->value['value'], 'IS NULL')
  ->condition($field, $this->value['value'], '<=');
  $this->query->add_where($this->options['group'],$or);
}
```

And you can choose that operator now in your Data Filter.

I hope this helps, any questions let me know as PM or comments, take care

Comment: Just wanted to note that it isn't recommended to hack modules. Better to create a new module that contains a custom handler.